# Экспорт личной статистики VK C#

Tags: c#, вконтакте

столкнулся с необходимостью экспортировать .xls файл статистики со страницы пользователя (логин/пароль имеются). Vk API не предоставляет возможность получить статистику пользователя, а только группы/приложения (на сколько мне известно). Каким образом можно (помимо Vk Api) произвести экспорт?